# C++ dequeueing issues... dequeue returns same element repeatedly

Tags: c++, linked-list, queue

So I have the below snippet of code...

```
for(int k=0; k<10; k++){
    State newState;
    newState = queue.dequeue();
    //...do stuff with `newState`...
}
```

The problem I'm having is that after hours of testing, I realized that `newState` dequeues the exact same instance of `State` every time the code gets to `newState = queue.dequeue()`, rather than popping a new element out in a FIFO fashion... I can't seem to figure out what exactly I'm doing wrong :/

Below is my Queue class .h and .cpp code...

```
//queue.h

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "state.h"

using namespace std;

// Node class
class Node {
public:
    State elem;
    Node* next;
    Node() {}
    State Elem() { return elem; }
    Node* Next() { return next; }
};

// Queue class
class Queue {
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
  public:
    Queue();
    ~Queue();
    bool isEmpty();
    int size();
    void enqueue(State);
    State dequeue();
};
```

and my .cpp file...

```
//queue.cpp

#include "queue.h"

#include <iostream>

Queue::Queue(){
    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
}

Queue::~Queue(){
    if(!isEmpty()){
        while(head){
            Node *del = head;
            head = head->next;
            delete del;
        }
    }
}

bool Queue::isEmpty(){
    return head == NULL;
}

int Queue::size(){
    int count = 0;
    if(isEmpty()){
        return count;
    } else {
        Node *temp = head;
        while(temp){
            temp = temp->next;
            count++;
        }
        delete temp;
        return count;
    }
}

//insert s to back of queue
void Queue::enqueue(State s){
    Node* newNode = new Node();
    newNode->elem = s;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    if(s.checkZ()){
        cout << "Puzzle solved!" << endl << endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    if(head==NULL){
        head = tail = newNode;
    } else {
        tail->next = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
    }
}

//remove State from front of queue
State Queue::dequeue(){
    if(isEmpty()){
        cout << "This puzzle has no solution." << endl;
        cout << "Exiting program..." << endl << endl;
        exit(0);
    } else {
        State ret = head->Elem();
        Node *del = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete del;
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help, and I'd be glad to show any other snippets of my code per request

EDIT: here's my copy constructor for State...

```
State::State(const State &rhs){
    pieces = rhs.pieces;
    pieceCount = rhs.pieceCount;
    rows = rhs.rows; cols = rhs.cols;
    currentState = rhs.currentState;
    prevStates = rhs.prevStates;
    prevStateCount = rhs.prevStateCount;
    moves = rhs.moves;
    moveCount = rhs.moveCount;
}
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question but: Your program's logic is tightly coupled to the implementation of `Queue`. It would make sense to make `Queue` a template class instead of hardcoding it to hold `State`s. The logic to solve the puzzle also shouldn't  be done inside the container but in the code that uses the container. If you separate these things, perhaps you'll find it easier to debug.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong in the `Queue` code. Perhaps there's a problem in `State`'s copy constructor?

Comment: Yeah, I know. I should change that. I've been on a bit of coding marathon as this program's due in 12 hours so I'm starting to get a bit sloppy. But from my tests, it seems that enqueue works fine. Size increments as it should. I'm thinking it has something to do with the way I assign newState, but I'm not sure...

Comment: Also not an answer but why not use std::queue<State> instead?

Comment: Ok, I updated the original question with my copy constructor for State... and for this assignment, we have to make all the data structures from scratch.

Comment: ok since I haven't the full source to State I just typedef'd `int` to be `State` and ran through a big stack of enqueues and dequeues (had to pull out the check function call too, sry). Your queue works fine, so all I can suggest is the code that is pushing your State value in is not pushing what you think it is.

Comment: @user2065121 Because some people want to, or need to, learn how to implement data structures. It's a terrific skill to have.

Answer (score 0):

In `size()`

```
delete temp;
```

while not dangerous, because temp is null at this point, it looks suspicious. You can also remove the `if/else` because `count` is not incremented when head is null.

Otherwise I cannot see why it should return the same element again and again. The only reason could be some code around, which inserts the same element more than once.